# Scrolling WebView overwrite surface

Tags: android, android-webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have come across a problem where a WebView overwrites other surfaces.

The problem occurs when we use an animating fragment transaction and the webview is scrolling.

In the two pictures below I try to illustrate the problem. The user is scrolling the WebView but decides to close the view by pressing back / or the close button in the bottom fragment. The WebView-fragment is then replaced by another fragment.

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(enterAnimation,exitAnimation);
transaction.addToBackStack(aFragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
transaction.replace(container, aFragment);
transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

But sometimes the bottom fragment is overwritten with part of the removed fragments WebView once the exit animation is completed.

I have only seen this issue on Android 4.4.

There is now an [open issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67136) in the AOSP issue tracker

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: If it only happens on 4.4 then this sounds like it may be a bug in the WebView graphics pipeline. Could you please prepare a repro (ideally an APK + source) and file a bug on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry ?

Comment: @marcin.kosiba it's commercial code not yet released so I've have to rip it to a new demonstration-project. But sure, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @marcin.kosiba It's done! https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67136

Comment: Thanks! It certainly looks like a legitimate bug.